# How to put data distributedly on all nodes on hadoop 2.6

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using a 3 node Hadoop 2.6 cluster.

```
hadoop fs -put data/sample.csv /tmp
```

This will save "sample.csv" in "/tmp" directory. This csv is having 1 billion record ( size 31 GB)

**Is this data distributed on all nodes?**

Do I need to change any configuration for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this command

```
hdfs fsck /tmp/sample.csv -files -blocks -locations
```

Command will give the associated blocks to your file and locations. In this case you will have 31 GB data on all the 3 nodes if your replication factor is 3.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this data distributed on all nodes?

Yes. If you write data to HDFS, it's always distributed.

It's not necessarily distributed on *all* nodes in general. With 3 nodes and a 31 GB file, it will certainly be. But if you have more nodes or a smaller file, it may not be. In general HDFS decides how to best distribute the file. By default it also replicates the file 3 ways.